# Sums $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac1{2n(n+1)}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}\right)?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What approach can be used to solve $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac1{2n(n+1)}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)}\right)?$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: There is nothing to solve, that is not the correct word here, you can ask about close form or evaluating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $2\sin(a) \cos(b) = \sin(a+b) + \sin(a-b)$, the sum can be written as

$$\frac 12 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left( \frac 1n \right) - \sin\left( \frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$ This is a telescoping sum, i.e. all but the first and last term cancel out. Notice that the last term will be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(\frac 1n )=0$. And so the sum equals

$$\frac 12 \sin (1)$$

Comment: Thanks ! this will be definitely helpful. 100% accurate